# How can I use "~" or "$HOME" in VisualStudioCode settings on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using settings sync between multiple windows pc with different usernames.

Some settings with path such as `vim.autoSwitchInputMethod.obtainIMCmd` might be `C:/Users/myname/im-select.exe`. However it cannot work if I replace the value to `~/im-select.exe` or `$HOME/im-select.exe` or `${env:HOME}/im-select.exe`.

So how should I set the value to make it work among all different pcs? Or how to make vscode to read environment variables ?

Comment: First, is the `HOME` environment variable set? Normally you have to set it manually on Windows systems

Comment: The equivalent to `HOME` on Windows is `USERPROFILE`

Comment: I had added `HOME`. `USERPROFILE` still cannot work.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that there is no variable expansion performed on the settings values with exception when the programmer decides to perform the expansion on a specific value explicitly! --- See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809